# Do you require to register as a partner to consume user data using OAuth?

Tags: oauth2

I am building an app that takes user data from salesforce using OAuth. Is there a way to do it without registering as a partner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be a partner to connect to force.com via REST and OAuth.  You may need to configure the instance to obtain client secrets etc but this depends on which oauth flow you are using.

The REST documentation describes this pretty well.

Comment: Which oauth flow lets you do that?

Comment: You should use the correct flow depending on your application. Please review the documentation. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_authentication.htm